# Datepicker disable today and tomorrow if

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I got some trouble making an awesome feature for my datepicker. The things i want to do is:

1. I want to disable TODAY, the user should not be able to select today's date
2. If todays time is 11AM, it should disable TOMORROW aswell

   ```
   $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
       lang: 'da',
       timepicker: false,
       format: 'd/m/Y',
       formatDate: 'Y/m/d',
       // minDate: new Date().getHours() >= 11 ? 1 : 0,
   });
   ```

I have been look around other examples on stackoverflow but nothing worked. So nows my time to try my luck!

Many thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this by manually computing the current time and disabling tomorrow date if it falls before the desired time in today context.

For which you can use `beforeShow` options of **jQuery DatePicker**; which will be triggered before datepicker display.

So, There you can calculate the current time and manipulate minDate as required ,

```
beforeShow : function(){
        var dateTime = new Date();
        var hour = dateTime.getHours();
        //If Hour is equal to 11AM disable past date including tomorrow and today
        if(hour  == 11){
            $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
        }
    }
```

#### Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D4AGz/371/).

Comment: Thanks for this. In your example above you have: `if(hour  == 11){` but your example fiddle has `if(hour  >= 11){`. Which one is correct?

Comment: @DavidAlsbright it depends on our use case. AS of the question the correct will be `==`.